# ObjectListView FormatRow flickering

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, objectlistview

I've had a problem with showing `TabPage` with many controls - the time between showing first and last control while loading (changing `SelectedTabPage`) was too long and it looked awful .I've tried using  double buffering but it didn't help . I've placed all the controls in one `UserControl` hoping it would somehow help loading controls .
Finally to prevent it i used method i found on stackoverflow :

```
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
 {
   get
    {
       CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
       cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
       return cp;
    }
 }
```

It resolved my problem but unfortunately causes another one.
Now moving mouse coursor from objectListView to Devexpress.xtraTabPage (or from xtraTabPage to OLV) causes `ObjectListView.FormatRow` flickering (`backColor`, `FrontColor`, `strikeout` etc. disappears for a millisecond(s))

So here are my questions . Is there any way to stop that weird flickering ? Or Maybe there is some other way to show all the controls in userControl at once  ?

Controls loading within `UserControl`(Controls from `Devexpress`: a few `TextEdits` , `xtraTabControl` , a few `CheckEdits`, `RadioButtons` , date and `TimeEdits` , `BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView` and 3 `LookUpEdits`. While loading `LookUpEdits` the popUp shows what additionally makes it look bad.

Comment: Did you try Suspedning/Resuming the layout where appropriate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx

Comment: Oh forgot about this question , sorry.  Unfortunately even suspending layout didnt work for me good enough. I've decided to change objectListView to Devexpress.XtraGridView , that is not the answer for my question , but I had no idea what to do , and it looks better now ;)

Comment: Else you can use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate of Container-Control. That should stop flickering too. But heared you solved you problem another way :)